# What's the best strategy for migrating a dual boot system to a bigger disk?

Tags: partition, dual-boot, dd, disk

I have a dual boot system with Windows and Debian on my laptop and I want to upgrade my disk from a 500GB to a 2TB one, while increasing the sizes of both OS partitions. Here is how things are setup:

```
root@faris:~# LC_ALL=C fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: Micron 2300 NVMe 512GB                  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6974F471-DAB3-4665-A578-591B2C8F5144

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     391167    389120   190M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    391168     653311    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    653312  350619647 349966336 166.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 966057984  968085503   2027520   990M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 968085504  997390335  29304832    14G Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6 997392384 1000214527   2822144   1.3G Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p7 350619648  352573439   1953792   954M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p8 352573440  354527231   1953792   954M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p9 354527232  966057983 611530752 291.6G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p9_crypt: 291.58 GiB, 313086967808 bytes, 611497984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg-root: 289.72 GiB, 311083139072 bytes, 607584256 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg-swap: 1.86 GiB, 2000683008 bytes, 3907584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: Generic         
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

I wanna give more space for nvme0n1p3 (the Windows partition) but also nvme0n1p9 (the Linux partition), which is a LUKS2 encrypted partition. Also notice the 3 "recovery" partitions at the end of the disk and the fact that there are 2 EFI partitions and a 128M "Microsoft Reserved" one. I don't know if there's some kind of disk encryption going on there for Windows. Those were there when I got the laptop and I just never removed them.

What should be the best strategy here? There are 3 types of approach I can think of: work on the device layer (`dd`), work on the file layer (`cp`) or full OS reinstalls.

1. Fully `dd if=/dev/nvme0 of=/dev/sda` and then find a way to move/resize partitions after this?

   - Is it even possible to move partitions around after I do this? I guess that would require me to move the right-most partitions to the real end one-byone and then later find a way to somehow tell everybody the new sizes and offsets. How would I even do this?
2. Somehow recreate the 9 paritions in the new disk with the same size, and then `dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p* of=/dev/sdaX` each one separately?

   - Does this even work at all since the offsets form partition starts will be different? Will I be able to resize things after that? I mean, I can run update-grub, but I'm not sure about other issues.
3. Create a Windows Restoration pendrive, disk, use it to restore the system on the 2TB drive, install Linux on the new driver while adjusting the Windows partition size, and then finally copy all the files in? I suppose this is probably the safest one, but doing reinstalls of everything does not sound fun. I would prefer to avoid it unless there's a good reason (like moving everything being also time-consuming!).
4. Any other approach? Are there any Unix GUI programs that can help me here besides DD?

PS: the 2TB disk is listed as SDA instead of NVMe because I'm using an USB adaptor for it right now. I'll swap them when I have a strategy.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you then going to use current NVMe drive in adapter? You cannot boot with duplicate UUIDs or GUIDs. Most UEFI systems do not like two ESPs per device? But if it works you could keep that. Ubuntu normally just installs to an  existing ESP. Do not know Windows, and best way to copy or reinstall it, but suggest new install of Ubuntu and restore from your normal backup. That proves your backup is good, or you can still update from old NVMe drive if backup is missing anything.

Comment: I intend to open the laptop and remove the old nvme disk and replace it with the new ones. So I guess duplicate UUIDs wouldn't be a problem at that point.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu will not install grub2 bootloader to external drive in UEFI boot mode. It defaults to internal drive regardless of any selection during install. If you reinstall once new NVMe drive in system, then not an issue. But if first installing to external drive: Second drive 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153